# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined at Search function - Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I have a `angular5-data-table` module that I am implementing. I was able to use its all functionalities. Additionally, I wanted to add a search functionality on it. I added the codes below (both html and typescript) and I started to receive `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` error.

My search html is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Search by full name" #query (keyup)="searchMember(query.value)" [(ngModel)]="filter.name">
```

And the code behind this `searchMember(query.value)` is:

```
searchMember(query: string) {
  let members = this.allMembers;
  if (this.filter.firstName) {
    members = members.filter(o => o.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
 }
  this.members = members;
  this.initializeTable(this.members);
  console.log(members);
}
```

Here is `initializeTable()`:

```
  private initializeTable(members: Member[]) {
    this.tableResource = new DataTableResource(members);
    this.tableResource.query({ offset: 0 }).then(items => this.items = items);
    this.tableResource.count().then(count => this.itemCount = count);
 }
```

And lastly, here are initializations:

```
filter: any = {};
tableResource: DataTableResource<Member>;
allMembers: Member[];
```

I am not sure I understood the error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the line of code here in the `DataTableResource` class:

https://github.com/brunano21/angular-4-data-table/blob/master/libs/datatable/src/tools/data-table-resource.ts#L9

It looks like the "query" method tries to slice it's own items, which is set in it's constructor.  You're doing that here:

```
this.tableResource = new DataTableResource(members);
```

So if `members` is not defined, it's going to fail to slice and throw that error.  Make sure your `members` are defined before initializing the data table.